# ListView error occurs in the onCreate method?

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to use a `ListView` which is just like on this page:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

I want to use `setContentView` and then use the `ListView` which I put on that layout. Here's my code:

```
public class ListViewTrainingsActivity extends ListActivity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);    // It gives me error here?

  final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
            "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra",
            "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina",
            "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan",
            "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium",
            "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia",
            "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Bouvet Island", "Brazil", "British Indian Ocean Territory",
            "British Virgin Islands"};

  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES));

  ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
      // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  });

}
  }
```

and I'm getting an error that says:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(306): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime(306): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.yahya.ListViewTrainings/com.yahya.ListViewTrainings.ListViewTrainingsActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
 E/AndroidRuntime(306):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
 .
 .
 .
 E/AndroidRuntime(306): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
 E/AndroidRuntime(306):     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:245)
 E/AndroidRuntime(306):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:201)
 E/AndroidRuntime(306):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
 E/AndroidRuntime(306):     at com.yahya.ListViewTrainings.ListViewTrainingsActivity.onCreate(ListViewTrainingsActivity.java:17)
```

I hope anybody can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: looks like this problem to me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error  `ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);` remove `android` and the reference that s added by eclipse to the `import` list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your layout `main.xml` you must have a `ListView` element with the id(extending `ListActivity` requires this):

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Also because you have extended the `ListActivity` class you can get the `ListView` by calling the method [`getListView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#getListView%28%29):

```
ListView lv = getListView();
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your listView id with this `android:id="@android:id/list"` check if this helps.